# Proof of McMahon's factorisatio numerorum result

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, dirichlet-series

I recently read that if the number of multiplicative partitions of $n$ is $a_n$, McMahon and Oppenheim observed that its Dirichlet series generating function $f(s)$ has the product representation

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {a_{n}}{n^{s}}}=\prod_{k=2}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{1-k^{-s}}}.$$

What is the proof for this? I didn't find any complete proof to the above correspondence. Does someone know where to find it? Or at least how it works?

Comment: The reason is the same as Euler's product formula for Riemann's zeta function. Try to see why this is true by rewriting $\frac{1}{1-k^{-s}}$ as $1 + \frac{1}{k^s} + \frac{1}{k^{2s}} + \cdots$ and expand a few terms.

Comment: @HwChu I understand the algebraic equality, but why does this correspond to the number of multiplicative partitions of $n$?

Comment: Your comment seems inconsistent with the background in your question. The number of multiplicative partitions of n is $a_n$ (see https://oeis.org/A001055 for the values). Now if these values are used as the coefficients of a Dirichlet series as in $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s}$, then the claim is that this Dirichlet series is equivalent to the product representation $\prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{1-k^{-s}}$.